# Which twitter client can synchronize unread tweets?

Tags: windows, linux, sync, android, twitter

Right now I'm forced to read all the tweets in a single client on a single device (TweetDeck on my Android phone).

If I would switch to another device and/or client, I would need to search for the last unread tweet, which is sometimes complicated (too many tweets).

So, the question: 
Is there a client who can keep the status (read/unread) on tweets across multiple devices? My target systems would be now Android and MS Windows, but also Linux might be handy.

Comment: Twitter doesn't track whether a tweet has been read or not so applications can only track tweets you've read on that application, perhaps something like Hootsuite or Tweetdeck might keep track of tweets that you've read on those applications but I can't find anything online that suggests that's the case.

Comment: Sure, twitter doesn't know... But for Tweetdeck for instance, I have also "tweetdeck account", whatever it is. But it is still not able to track my unread tweets (it is even not able to synchronize my columns)

Answer (score 2):

Had exactly the same problem and found http://tweetmarker.net/ very helpful. Basically you can choose from any clients listed on the site and it can even sync between different clients.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it for myself, but [Echofon](http://www.echofon.com/) [claims](http://www.echofon.com/push-sync-guide.html) to sync your unread/read-status between all their different clients and platforms. There is a Firefox-Plugin (Windows, Mac, Linux) and a Windows client is "coming soon", but unfortunately there's no Android client (yet?).

Comment: Now they have an Android client, but it looks like they've dropped the Firefox plugin.

Comment: They also dropped the Windows client.