# How to sync unread tweets between iPhone and Mac?

Tags: mac, sync, iphone, twitter

As an heavy Twitter lists user, both on my iPhone and my Macs, I am looking for a way to sync the tweets I still have to read on my different devices.

On my Mac, I am using Tweetdeck and Tweetbot on my iPhone. I find these two applications doing a good job except for the synchronisation.

I tried the Tweetbot Mac application so that I could sync my tweets between my Macs and my iPhone but found the application not as good as the Tweetdeck client in terms of tweets readability.

Open to any suggestion.

A similar question was asked 6 years ago [here](https://superuser.com/questions/300954/which-twitter-client-can-synchronize-unread-tweets/). Thought asking the question again, would be better that posting a comment in such old thread.

Comment: Actually, the accepted method is to Bounty the existing question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which twitter client can synchronize unread tweets?](https://superuser.com/questions/300954/which-twitter-client-can-synchronize-unread-tweets)